# Export namespace should be first transformed by `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from` - Previous solutions didn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm facing this issue in my app. I know there are two other questions about this topic. But because I don't have reputation, I can't comment or ask questions on them. Which makes me come here...

I've implemented Redux on my application. (I'm new to it)
At first, everything worked fine.. and now, this is what I'm getting:

> ```
> Export namespace should be first transformed by `@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from`.
> ```

I've tried adding:

```
plugins: [
  "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
],
```

To my babel.config file. Then expo start -c...
Still facing this issue.

Unfortunately, I can't share my code here, as it's confidential. But is there anything else I could try?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the plugin in babel config.js file as directed by plugin installation instructions.
**Note** that the reanimated plugin should be added at **last** in plugins array like this:

```
babel.config.js
module.exports = {
      ...
      plugins: [
          ...
          'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      ],
  };
```

**CAUTION**
Reanimated plugin has to be listed last.

**INFO**
After adding the react-native-reanimated/plugin to your project you may encounter a false-positive "Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet" error. In most cases, this can be fixed by cleaning the application's cache. Depending on your workflow or favourite package manager that could be done by:

***yarn start --reset-cache***

***npm start -- --reset-cache***

***expo start -c***

or other.

[https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/https://)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did! Thank you for the response and help!